# Simular um relatório Mestre/Detalhe com foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma tabela da seguinte forma:

```
public class Producao
{
    string unidade;
    string profissional;
    string procedimento;
}
```

Eu consigo pegar todos os registros armazenados na tabela e jogá-los em uma lista `listaProducao`. E listá-los através de um `foreach` da seguinte forma:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Unidade</td>
    <td>Profissional</td>
    <td>Procedimento</td>
</tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.unidade</td>
            <td>@item.profissional</td>
            <td>@item.procedimento</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

O resultado é semelhante ao mostrado abaixo:

```
unidade - profissional - procedimento
   1           1              1
   1           2              1
   1           2              2
   1           3              1
   1           3              3
```

O que eu quero é gerar um resultado assim:

```
UNIDADE 1
--------------------
PROFISSIONAL 1
--------------------
procedimento 1
--------------------
PROFISSIONAL 2
--------------------
procedimento 1
procedimento 2
--------------------
PROFISSIONAL 3
--------------------
procedimento 1
procedimento 3
```

Vejam que o resultado é semelhante a um relatório Mestre / Detalhe, onde lista primeiro a unidade, todos os profissionais dela e seus procedimentos. Depois lista outra unidade caso tenha na tabela.

Alguma dica de como fazer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seguindo esse output que você pediu, você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
<table>
    @foreach (var unidade in Model.GroupBy(i => i.unidade))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>UNIDADE @unidade.Key</td>
        </tr>
        foreach (var profissional in unidade.GroupBy(i => i.profissional))
        {
            <tr>
                <td>PROFISSIONAL @profissional.Key</td>
            </tr>
            foreach (var p in profissional)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>Procedimento @p.procedimento</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Alisson, esse exemplo funcionou normalmente em MVC, mas tentei usá-lo agora em WindowsForms e o mesmo não está dando certo. Você pode fazer um exemplo em WindowsForms também? Abraço.

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo como você está tentando exibir os resultados? Incluindo em algum `DataGrid`? Qual parte não está funcionando?

Comment: Se eu faço assim na primeira linha: `foreach (Producao unidade in listaProducao.GroupBy(i => i.unidade))` ele dá erro na segunda linha `foreach (var profissional in unidade.GroupBy(i => i.profissional))` diz que `unidade` não tem um GetEnumerator

Comment: Alisson, consegui resolver. Valeu mesmo assim

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo tente utilizar `foreach (var unidade in listaProducao` (utilize **var** ao invés de Producao).